# Having issues making math calculations in python, I am receiving the wrong answer in the end

Tags: python

Beginner here. I've been following the 100 days of code course on Udemy and I have been trying to figure out the Tip Calculator project.

https://gyazo.com/285baf25f0c803fc893faa32d23d9fd1

I am receiving the wrong tip per person. For example I make the total bill amount 40.53, percent tip 15 and make it a 3 way split, and it gives me 15.33... and if I do this online on another program it would give me 15.54. Any tips for a beginner?

Comment: Please copy/paste your code as text into the body of your question and format accordingly.

Comment: images of code, really?

Comment: pls read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that it is converting those numbers to integers, however, integers don't have decimal places and also always round down, you need to use floats for maximum precision

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, as BeRT2me has requested to see, it sounds like the variable you are assigning your intermediary total to is being set as an integer or is being truncated/rounded down perhaps by the output type of a function call you are making/returning.

Likely, change it to be an appropriate form of decimal type.

e.g. Using your values, 40.53 * 1.15 = 46.6095

46.6095 / 3 = 15.5365 (or 15.54 rounded to 2 decimal places)
46 / 3 = 15.33 (rounded to 2 decimal places)

If you are using that code example of total_final_bill. The type would be implicitly set as an integer since you are adding to integer values.

You are performing an implicit rounding function on the tip_amount and the total_bill by using the int() function. These should not be integers as they are decimal/float values.

So, each time you use int() other than int(tip_percent) and int(split_question) which are actually integer values for your formulas you are rounding the decimals.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for not putting the code in, when i first tried to put the code in it gave me an error. first time on here, i'll fix it next time i ask